# Difference between if (!file) and if (file == NULL)

Tags: c, file, fopen

Is there any difference between these 2 versions of checking if file is actually opened:

```
FILE *file = fopen(fname, "rb");
if (!file)
{
    exit(1);
}
```

And

```
FILE *file = fopen(fname, "rb");
if (file == NULL)
{
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: The only difference is how easy the code is to read. In that respect, in my opinion, the latter is better.

Comment: They are, by definition, computationally identical.  The only differences are of style, and thus endlessly debatable.

Comment: The only difference is how easy the code is to read. In that respect, in my opinion, the former is better. Doing needless additional comparisons just adds noise.

Comment: Regardless of your personal preferences, you need to recognise both. You're going to encounter either style and you need to know they are essentially equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these are equivalent.

The logical NOT operator `!` is defined as follows in section 6.5.3.3p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The  result  of  the  logical  negation  operator `!` is  0  if  the
> value  of  its  operand  compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its
> operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`.
> **The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`**

So `!file` is the same as `0 == file`.  The value 0 is considered a **null pointer constant**, defined in section 6.3.2.3p3:

> An  integer  constant  expression  with  the  value  0,  or  such  an
> expression  cast  to  type `void *`, is called a *null pointer
> constant*.<sup>66)</sup>  If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer
> type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to
> compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function
>
> 66 ) The macro `NULL` is defined in <stddef.h> (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19

This means that comparing a pointer to 0 is the same as comparing it to `NULL`.  So `!file` and `file == NULL` are the same.

Comment: Notably, they're the same (for the reasons given) even on systems where a NULL pointer has a different bit pattern than an integer with value 0.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h

`<stddef.h>` defines NULL as literally 0.

What makes a conditional statement in C be 'true', is that it is not 0. That is it.

The `!` operator converts non-zero values to 0, and 0 values to 1.
The `==` operator returns 1 if the operands are equal and 0 otherwise.

Your two statements are logically equivalent. (probably) The only difference is style or personal preference. You might find it interesting to look at the compiled assembly to dig deeper.

Comment: "*`<stddef.h>` defines NULL as literally 0.*" It *might* do so on your system, but it *need not*. It just has to define it to be a null pointer constant, which might be a compiler-dependent builtin like `__null`.

Comment: This is a fair point, but from the perspective of the programmer it is always 0 - if that weren't true conditional statements wouldn't work on systems that define NULL to values other than 0.

Comment: Well, `((void*)0)` is also common in C when there is no builtin providing extra-capabilities (specifically, warning if not used in a pointer-context nor comparison to itself or other null pointer constant).